# How to create ModelView programmatically?

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

I have create xaml object with Datacontext ViewModel.

How to create it programmatically, not in xaml?

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:CreateMultiPaneStockChartsViewModel x:Key="ViewModel" />
</Window.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="Grid">
    <local:CreateMultiPaneStockCharts DataContext="{StaticResource ViewModel}" />
</Grid>
```

Or how to binding datacontext programmatically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code behind:

```
var view = new CreateMultiPaneStockCharts
{
    DataContext = Resources["ViewModel"]
}

Grid.Children.Add(view);
```

Using the concept of WPF Data Templating, you would create a DataTemplate resource that is automatically applied for the appropriate view model type, like:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type local:CreateMultiPaneStockChartsViewModel}">
        <local:CreateMultiPaneStockCharts />
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
```

The DataTemplate would automatically be applied if you assign a view model instance to (for example) the `Content` property of a ContentControl, or if you would assign or bind the `ItemsSource` property of an ItemControl to a collection of view model instances.